# ZeroBraneStudio not able to attach it to openresty in localhost

Tags: zerobrane

I followed the steps in the website. snippet of my **nginx conf**

```
http {
 underscores_in_headers on;
 lua_package_path '/opt/luapoc/lua/?.lua;/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/?/?.lua;/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/?.lua;;';
 lua_package_cpath '/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/bin/clibs/?.dylib;;';
 init_by_lua_block{
   num = require("numbers")
   data = num.getrandom()
   if data then
   ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, "data is" .. data)
   end
 }
```

**numbers.lua**

```
require('mobdebug').start("192.168.1.155")

local M={}
function M.getrandom()
print("random function called") -- I put a break point here. 
return math.random()
end
return M
```

I took my IP address my ifconfg inetaddress.

I went to ZBS and set the project directory from numbers file. Then started the debug by Project -> Start debugger server.

Eventhough I gave the IP address in the require('mobdebug').start("192.168.1.155") it is staring the debug server on local host.

I am starting the nginx and expecting the flow stop at the  break point I put at numbers.lua but its not.

Any idea was what's causing the ZBS to not receive debug signal?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to start the debugger server in the IDE by going to `Project | Start Debugger Server`. It's disabled by default as it throws a firewall warning when started on some systems. You can also enable it by default by using [AutoStartDebug](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/autostartdebug.lua) plugin.

If this still doesn't help, try running the same script outside of nginx, from the command line to see if it works there.